# Android use AppBarLayout instead of Toolbar

Tags: android, android-activity, toolbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am using a normal AppCompat Toolbar in my project. In one of my fragments I want to use the AppBarLayout toolbar and TabLayout instead of the normal Toolbar. How can I switch between those two toolbars? I tried inflating the AppBar Toolbar but it just puts it below the appcompat one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ToolBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) is a view which can be placed anywhere, In case you are trying to use this is an Actionbar then don't use AppComact ActionBar. For disabling that you need to choose appropriate theme for application like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and for Toolbar use Actionbar theme like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

You can view complete thread in more details for

Comment: I am using the AppCompat ActionBar on my project. I want to use the actionbar inside the appbarlayout for one fragment instead of the appcompat actionbar. bcus I am in a fragment, I already have the appcompat actionbar displayed, but I want to use the appbarlayout toolbar. How to switch between those then?

Comment: I think better would be if you Toolbar for application with AppComact theme of NoActionBar.  In your current scenario you need the change the theme of that activity where your Fragment is displayed so that you will be able to use ToolBar.